# Using Sqlite in a web application

Tags: php, mysql, database, sqlite, web-applications

I'm currently developping an application which allows doctors to dinamically generate invoices. The fact is, each doctors requires 6 differents database tables, and there could be like 50 doctors connected at the same time and working with the database (writing and reading) at the same time.

What I wanted to know is if the construction of my application fits. For each doctors, I create a personnal Sqlite3 database (all database are secure) which only him can connect to. I'll have like 200 Sqlite database, but is there any problems ? I thought it could be better than using a big MySQL database for everyone.

Is this solution viable ? Will I have problems to deal with ? I never did such an application with so many users, but I thought it could be the best solution

Comment: Why does it have to be separate databases, really? Why not separate databases on a MySQL server, if it's inevitable?

Comment: Each doctor has different data, and a lot of data, but is it okay if i have like 1000 different tables on MySQL ? each table could have like 1000 rows of data in it

Comment: Why would you even have different tables? Just have a column which identifies the doctor responsible for the data in that row.

Comment: But it would mean iterate through all the table to find the data for each doctor ? if i have only one table, it will mean at least ten thousand data in each table.. And if one of the doctor does a mistake, all the table is corrupted

Comment: If you have proper *indexes* on the tables you're never "iterating ten thousand data"... And the doctor can't make such a mistake (hopefully, because he doesn't have direct access to the database), only your code could. If you really want to separate the data, at least just create separate *databases* with different SQL users with their individual access rights; that would still make sense if you're really keen on security.

Comment: But, by using multiple Sqlite database, will I have any performance problems ? I also need Sqlite because some doctors will want the source code, so they just have to put all the fils on their FTP to see it working..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, to answer your question: no, you probably will not have any significant problems if a single sqlite database is used only by one person (user) at a time. If you highly value certain edge cases, like the ability to move some users/databases to another server, this might be a very good solution.

But it is not a terribly good design. The usual way is to have all data in the same database, and tables having a field which identifies which rows belong to which users. The application code is responsible for maintaining security (i.e. not to let users see data which doesn't belong to them), and indexes in the database (which you should use in all cases, even in your own design) are responsible for making it fast.

There are a large number of tutorials which could help you to make a better database design; a random google result is http://www.profsr.com/sql/sqless02.htm .

Comment: My idea was to name each database after an encrypted version of their password's hash, thus they should be the only one to access it

Comment: @solarBanana Nope, bad idea. Anyone who has access to the database in the first place can list all databases that exists. That's no security improvement and will only confuse you.

Comment: Just adding that you could have 'shadow tables'. Create a view from a query, name this view with the username and ony alow this user to access this table. this will add a little bit of data security, no user is going to accidentally delete the data for another. Also, being in the medical industy,  if there is an 'authorisation process' they should be able to change thier 'authority' (or start at the lower auth level, and increase it). I know from when I was entering data sometimes you didn't want full authorisation of results untill you had all the results available.